# how to obtain the json field name?

Tags: json

The JSON structure I am using is as follows :

```
{

    "marketingModelPresentation": {
        "colors": [ … ],
        "colorThemes": [ … ],
        "asMap": { … },
        "label": {
            "fr": "Nouvelle Clio Campus"
        },
        "order": "000000",
        "key": "CL2",
        "equipementsPresentation": [ … ],
        "technicalSpecificationsPresentation": [ … ],
        "versionsPresentation": [
            {
                "presentationGroup": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "presentationGroup": {
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "versionItem": {
                                            "versionIdSpecCode": "VEC324_ALGE",
                                            "label": {
                                                ***"fr": "Nouvelle Clio Campus*** 
City"
                                            },
                                            "order": "0",
                                            "key": "VEC324_ALGE",
                                            "versionId": {
                                                "countrySpecCode": "ALGE",
                                                "versionSeq": "324"
                                            },
                                            "showableSpecCodes": [
                                                "QPA$MV",
                                                "QPA$O",
                                                "DA",
                                                "ABS",
                                                "CA",
                                                "LAC",
                                                "VT",
                                                "RETROE",
                                                "ADAC",
                                                "DRAP53",
                                                "HARM05",
                                                "2ATRPH",
                                                "FBANAR",
                                                "CTMOT",
                                                "PROSCS",
                                                "LVCIPE",
                                                "RSEC01",
                                                "COREHA",
                                                "JANTOL",
                                                "FIPOU",
                                                "RAD54A",
                                                "CLESUP",
                                                "1149CC",
                                                "055KW",
                                                "D4F"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "versionItem": {
                                            "versionIdSpecCode": "VEC325_ALGE",
                                            "label": {
                                                "fr": "Nouvelle Clio Campus"
                                            },
                                            "order": "1",
                                            "key": "VEC325_ALGE",
                                            "versionId": {
                                                "countrySpecCode": "ALGE",
                                                "versionSeq": "325"
                                            },
                                            "showableSpecCodes": [
                                                "QPA$MV",
                                                "QPA$O",
                                                "DA",
                                                "ABS",
                                                "CAREG",
                                                "LAC",
                                                "VSTLAR",
                                                "RETROE",
                                                "PROJAB",
                                                "ADAC",
                                                "DRAP53",
                                                "HARM05",
                                                "2ATRPH",
                                                "FBANAR",
                                                "CTMOT",
                                                "PROSCS",
                                                "LVCIPE",
                                                "RSEC01",
                                                "COREHA",
                                                "JANALU",
                                                "FIPOU",
                                                "RAD54A",
                                                "CLESUP",
                                                "1149CC",
                                                "055KW",
                                                "D4F"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "label": {
                                    "fr": "Nouvelle Clio Campus"
                                },
                                "order": "0_0",
                                "key": "ENS_MDL2P1SERIELIM2"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "label": {
                        "fr": "Clio Campus"
                    },
                    "order": "0",
                    "key": "ENS_MDL2P1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

I am trying to get the 'fr' inside the 'label' which is inside the 'version presentation'. I have tried so many times and here is my coding :

```
public class GetRestfulExampleSucces {

public string jsonStr {get;set;}
public Pagereference getJSONFromREST() {
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://dz.co.rplug.renault.com/pres/BAWg'); 
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/JSON');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
        jsonStr= res.getBody();
        List<String> calOut = new List<String>();
        system.debug('jsonStr>>>>>>>>>>>>'+jsonStr);
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr);
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME){
                String fieldName = parser.getText();
                system.debug('fieldName >>>>>>>>>>>>'+fieldName );
                if(fieldName == 'versionsPresentation'){
                    while(parser.nextToken() != null){                    
                        if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME){
                            String Mname = parser.getText();
                            system.debug('Mname >>>>>>>'+Mname );
                                if(Mname == 'fr'){
                                parser.nextToken();
                                 string version=parser.getText();
                                system.debug('version>>>>>>>'+version);
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return null;
        }

}
```

By using the above coding , I am getting again all the field values . Please provide me a solution for my query.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: `JSONParser` is a apex class correct ? so  why don't you try to get `fr` from that.. If you don't mind can you share you `JSONParser` class as well?

Comment: JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr); this method is used to parse the response which we got from webservice url.I didn create any apex clase to parse this

Comment: Uma.. try with https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex to generate apex class for your json then after deserialize your JSOn then it will be easy to get `fr `

Comment: I am getting the endpoint url dynamically from "custom settings".so each time the user cannot generate the JSON 2 Apex class

Comment: i run your code in DE and it works fine for me. What is not working for you?

Comment: am geeting all the field names for'fr'.eg:My expected output is: "Nouvelle Clio Campus" and "Nouvelle Clio Campus"           BUt the actual output is:"Nouvelle Clio Campus" and "Nouvelle Clio Campus"  ,Nouvelle Clio Campus and so on.ALl the fields inside"colors also am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get field names as:

```
String jsonStr ='{ "marketingModelPresentation": { "colors": [], "colorThemes": [], "asMap": {}, "label": { "fr": "Nouvelle Clio Campus" }, "order": "000000", "key": "CL2", "equipementsPresentation": [], "technicalSpecificationsPresentation": [], "versionsPresentation": [ { "presentationGroup": { "items": [ { "presentationGroup": { "items": [ { "versionItem": { "versionIdSpecCode": "VEC324_ALGE", "label": { "fr": "Nouvelle Clio Campus*** City" }, "order": "0", "key": "VEC324_ALGE", "versionId": { "countrySpecCode": "ALGE", "versionSeq": "324" }, "showableSpecCodes": [ "QPA$MV", "QPA$O", "DA", "ABS", "CA", "LAC", "VT", "RETROE", "ADAC", "DRAP53", "HARM05", "2ATRPH", "FBANAR", "CTMOT", "PROSCS", "LVCIPE", "RSEC01", "COREHA", "JANTOL", "FIPOU", "RAD54A", "CLESUP", "1149CC", "055KW", "D4F" ] } }, { "versionItem": { "versionIdSpecCode": "VEC325_ALGE", "label": { "fr": "Nouvelle Clio Campus" }, "order": "1", "key": "VEC325_ALGE", "versionId": { "countrySpecCode": "ALGE", "versionSeq": "325" }, "showableSpecCodes": [ "QPA$MV", "QPA$O", "DA", "ABS", "CAREG", "LAC", "VSTLAR", "RETROE", "PROJAB", "ADAC", "DRAP53", "HARM05", "2ATRPH", "FBANAR", "CTMOT", "PROSCS", "LVCIPE", "RSEC01", "COREHA", "JANALU", "FIPOU", "RAD54A", "CLESUP", "1149CC", "055KW", "D4F" ] } } ], "label": { "fr": "Nouvelle Clio Campus" }, "order": "0_0", "key": "ENS_MDL2P1SERIELIM2" } } ], "label": { "fr": "Clio Campus" }, "order": "0", "key": "ENS_MDL2P1" } } ] } }';
Map<String,Object> jsonKeys = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonStr);

// Iterate all keys
for(String field : jsonKeys.keySet())
{
   System.debug(' Field Name : '+field);
}
```

Update: tested the same json in dev org. It returns `marketingModelPresentation`

[image]

Comment: jsonkeys returns "{marketingModelPresentation={asMap={mapRepresentation={map={105KW={presentationItem={key=105KW, label={fr=105 KW}, order=5}}, 110KW={presentationItem={key=110KW, label={fr=110 KW}, order=6}},......." field returns :marketingModelPresentation